# Filter in KQL arrays

Tags: kql

I have a database that one of its columns represents a JSON array. The array is an array or arrays with numbers, like `[[1], [2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8]]`. I want to filter rows where one of the arrays inside has at least 3 elements.

I used this KQL:

```
traces
| where message has "Items per slot"
| extend items = parse_json(customDimensions["ItemsPerSlot"])
| where ??? // There is a slot with at least 3 items
```

But how can I write this `where` condition?

Comment: If `customDimensions` is indeed of *dynamic* type (and therefore you can use `customDimensions["ItemsPerSlot"]`), then *parse_json* has no effect.

Comment: The `customDimensions["ItemsPerSlot"]` is a string that represents JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let traces = datatable(id:int, message:string, customDimensions:dynamic)
[
    1 ,"Items per slot" ,dynamic({"ItemsPerSlot": [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8]]})
   ,2 ,"Items per slot" ,dynamic({"ItemsPerSlot": [[1], [2,3], [8]]})
];
traces
| where message has "Items per slot"
| extend items = customDimensions["ItemsPerSlot"]
| mv-apply item = items on (where array_length(item) >= 3 | take 1 | project-away item)
```

| id | message | customDimensions | items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Items per slot | {"ItemsPerSlot":[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8]]} | [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8]] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WQu07EQAxF%200j5h6utEmm22F1eyipb0dAhUUYRMomVDGQm0YxhiQj/Tl4UQIld2NK1j3XdsEAcFeyRoiQZ86nhSJeJtqJg2HuqOPHitK0UilcvrbnVhq3XrfVJ2VsyuojDIAsDjLGD2twJG4%20OHXzTygZqnYo%20Fume3cMkJMiyXa6Q7dVhKhfqUl2p66m9yfPPeCaq/T%20IKyY/hsHiMgwGnGt2/G0NNXn85k9T/C5sS%20hZSf84z34ezqcV87alrmv6dam1iJZb5Bz1jw3bSupoFmOcUhwwQOiFx6cN6Fz7zIVs6UwrIP4CYam%20JZ0BAAA=)